# How can I save multiple files in one, just like in a ZipFile?

Tags: c#, uwp

If I want to export my things i did inside of my app, I need to save two pictures and one text file. This is obviously annoying for the user, as he needs to move three files around.

If I put pictures into a word file and save it as a .docx, I can open it as a ZipFile and see that it actually just contains a lot of xml files and the pictures I added.

I want my app to do the same, create a .myappextension file that contains the other 3 files. But I have no idea how to achieve this. My output would be one string and two images, which I can all save on their own already. Before actually saving it I have an IRandomAccessStream.

In short, can I compile three IRandomAccessStreams into one file?

Comment: So why not put that 3 files into zip archive?

Comment: As you've seen with a .docx, just because the extension isn't .zip doesn't mean that you can't use ZIP compression (or some other compression format).

Comment: If you want to know how to deal with Zip files to store multiple files I have an example https://comentsys.wordpress.com/2017/06/16/universal-windows-platform-zipfile-app/ you can check that out as link only answers aren't allowed but feel free to look through that if it is useful

Answer (score 3):

Just create a zip file, as long as `System.IO.Compression` namespace's classes are available for uwp.

[System.IO namespaces for UWP apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt185496.aspx)